# MySQL my.cnf: innodb_log_file_size is missing

Tags: mysql, innodb, mysql-5.5, percona, backup, xtrabackup

How to set `innodb_log_file_size` to MySQL database if there is no `innodb_log_file_size` in **my.cnf** configuration file? I'd like to backup via *Percona Xtrabackup* and the backup crashes at this point telling me that my `innodb_log_file_size` is different than it expects.

Answer (score 2):

Login to mysql and run this

```
SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'innodb_log_file_size';
```

or this

```
SELECT variable_value FROM information_schema.global_variables
WHERE variable_name = 'innodb_log_file_size';
```

This will give you the size mysqld has. [The default for MySQL 5.5 is 5M](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_log_file_size).

Whatever number that turns up should be placed in `my.cnf`. If it is not set, then place this

```
[mysqld]
innodb_log_file_size = (Whatever the filesize of ib_logfile0 is)
```

Try out xtrabackup after adding this to `my.cnf`.